# Customize Release Button in Bill and Adjustment Screen of Acumatica ERP System (Version 2021 R1)

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I need to create some customize code for Release process in Bill and Adjusment entry screen.
I've already create DAC Extension for APInvoice, APTran, APTaxTran & GLTran, please see the following code.

**1). APInvoiceExt (DAC Extension)**

```
using PX.Data;
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APInvoiceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APInvoice>
  {
     #region UsrJadeRefNbr
     public abstract class usrJadeRefNbr : IBqlField{}
     [PXDBString(50, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
     [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Jade Ref. Nbr.")]
     public virtual string UsrJadeRefNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

**2). APTranExt (DAC Extension)**

```
using PX.Data;
using SGLCustomizeProject;
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
  {
      #region UsrJobOrderNbr
      public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlField{}
      [PXDBString(25, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="Job Order Nbr")]
      [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD,
                        Where<JobOrderNbr.status,
                            Equal<statusActive>>>),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.status),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.usrJobOrderNoRef))]
      public string UsrJobOrderNbr
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

     #endregion
  }
}
```

**3). APTaxTranExt (DAC Extension)**

```
using PX.Data;
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class APTaxTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTaxTran>
    {
        #region UsrNoSeriFaktur
        public abstract class usrNoSeriFaktur : IBqlTable { }
        [PXDBString(50, IsFixed = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "No Seri Faktur / Additional Narration")]
        public string UsrNoSeriFaktur { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**4). GLTranExt (DAC Extension)**

```
using PX.Data;
using SGLCustomizeProject;
namespace PX.Objects.GL
{
    public class GLTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.GL.GLTran>
    {
        #region UsrJobOrderNbr
        public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlField { }
        [PXDBString(25, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Job Order Nbr")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD,
                          Where<JobOrderNbr.status,
                              Equal<statusActive>>>),
                  //typeof(JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD),
                  typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
                  typeof(JobOrderNbr.status))]
        public string UsrJobOrderNbr { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrNoSeriFaktur
        public abstract class usrNoSeriFaktur : IBqlTable { }
        [PXDBString(75, IsFixed = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "No Seri Faktur / Additional Narration")]
        public string UsrNoSeriFaktur { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region UsrInvoiceNbr
        public abstract class usrInvoiceNbr : IBqlTable { }
        [PXDBString(60, IsFixed = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Ref. / Customer Order")]
        public string UsrInvoiceNbr { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And then I need to Extend the APInvoiceEntry BLC to custom the Release button, and the following is the source code that I've created.

**5. APInvoiceEntry_Extension (BLC Extension)**

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using PX.Objects.GL;
   namespace PX.Objects.AP
   {
        public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
        {
            #region Customize Button Release
            public PXAction<APInvoice> release;
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
            [PXProcessButton]
            public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>((graph) =>
                {
                    graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
                    {
                        APInvoice api = PXResult<APInvoice>.Current;
                        string refNbr = api.RefNbr;
                        if (api != null && api.InvoiceNbr != null)
                        {
                            GLTranExt glEx = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>((GLTran)e.Row);
                            glEx.UsrInvoiceNbr = api.InvoiceNbr;
                        }

                        APTran aptran = PXResult<APTran>.Current;
                        if (aptran != null)
                        {
                            APTranExt apTranEx = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExt>(aptran);

                            if (aptran != null && apTranEx.UsrJobOrderNbr != null)
                            {
                                GLTranExt glex = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>((GLTran)e.Row);
                                glex.UsrJobOrderNbr = apTranEx.UsrJobOrderNbr;
                            }
                        }

                        APTaxTran aptax = PXResult<APTaxTran>.Current;
                        if (aptax != null)
                        {
                            APTaxTranExt aptaxEx = PXCache<APTaxTran>.GetExtension<APTaxTranExt>(aptax);
                            if (aptax != null && aptaxEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur != null)
                            {
                                GLTranExt gltEx = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>((GLTran)e.Row);
                                gltEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur = aptaxEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur;

                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                return Base.release.Press(adapter);
            }
            #endregion
        }
     }
```

And then I go to the system to check the result.
[image]

And then I check on Journal Transaction Screen to make sure the result. But I got blank value for the custom field (Job Order Nbr & No Seri faktur), while (Vendor Ref) work fine.
[image]

And then I've tried to debug the code, and I got the cause of the problem.
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using current. try selecting it with the .select(Base);

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. It give the error message "PXResult<APTran> does not contain a definition for 'Select'."